# How is a Windows phone removed from Microsoft account?

Tags: microsoft-account, find-my-phone

My Windows phone (Microsoft Lumia 535) was stolen last month. So I tried to find the location by 'Find My Windows Phone' option from my Microsoft account, but it was not updated after that. I was monitoring the location & time frequently, but unfortunately without my presence, the device was removed from my account last week. I don't know how it is possible. Based on that, i have some questions:

1. How was the device removed from my account without my presence?
2. If factory reset done on that mobile, will the registered account be removed?
3. Is it possible to use Windows Phone without registering account?
4. After factory reset, if register new MS account, will the system notify to last account user by mail? if not, how to find that newly registered account?
5. Is it possible to change Windows Phone IMEI number?
6. Any options to track that IMEI or newly registered account?

Please clarify.

Comment: If you still have a note of the IMEI, then you should pass that information onto law enforcement, especially if someone else has registered the device, as they should be able to track it down (perhaps with Microsoft's help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the answers to your questions.

1. Yes it is quite possible to wipe out a windows phone without using the signed in Microsoft account by using specific key combination during booting even if you have a PIN on your device. Also if you haven't a PIN on your lock screen then it is perfectly possible that someone may reach your settings and perform a hard reset on your phone as it does not require your presence or your account's password.
2. After a hard reset is performed, all user data is wiped out from the phone and OS is set to it's factory settings hence **registered account will be removed ** .
3. Yes it is possible to use Windows Phone without getting signed-in however one won't be able to go through account-based services such as Store and Xbox etc.
4. No system will not notify the previous user at all because after resetting it will **forget** everything about previous user. It is merely impossible to find out who is signed-in to your device.
5. No, it is not possible to change IMEI no.
6. Tracking newly registered account is also impossible.

Comment: I put PIN lock on lock screen. Is it possible to hard reset?

Comment: Per the first point, it is possible to perform a hard reset of a device without getting past the PIN entry

Comment: Sorry for that @Rowland Shaw i have updated my answer and yes it is possible to hard reset even if one don't know the PIN.